# Debugging Flutter app from a Raspberry Pi - Device not detected

Tags: android, flutter, raspberry-pi, adb, android-sdk-tools

I'm creating an ultra portable app development setup with a Raspberry Pi 4 8GB. Since Android Studio is not compatible with ARM I have installed VS Code and installing the Android SDK manually. Here's what I have so far:

- Installed Ubuntu to the Raspberry Pi
- Installed Flutter 2.4 using `snap`
- Installed Chromium and pointed `CHROME_EXECUTABLE` to it in `.bashrc`
- Installed VS Code with Dart and Flutter plugins
- Installed the Android SDK using `apt install android-sdk`
- Installed the Android Command Line Tools from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools)  and added them to my PATH
- Installed `platform-tools`, `platforms;android-28` and `build-tools;28.0.3` using `sdkmanager --install`
- Agreed to Android licenses using `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

However when I plug my phone in (previously used for debugging with my laptop running Android Studio), `flutter devices` doesn't detect it, it only shows Chrome as a device. In VS Code when I go to debug, I therefore only get Chrome as an option, which incidentally does work fine for web debugging. My phone has "USB debugging is on" on the handset.

A few things I noticed are:

- Despite installing the command line tools, they are completely ommited from `flutter doctor` (see output below). As far as I can tell they are installed but I am not sure if I need to add something to my `.bashrc`?
- I tried setting up an emulator but `emulator` isn't available as a package from `sdkmanager` and VS Code says `avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK` when try to create one through there. I didn't pursue this since I expect that would be a bit heavy for the pi anyway so rather debug on my actual device. I just presume that the emulator doesn't supprt ARM or something.
- If I enter `which adb` into terminal I get `/usr/bin/adb` rather than `/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb`. Both seem to work and this is the output of `adb devices`:

```
List of devices attached
6369e875    device
```

Here is the output of `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.4.0-5.0.pre.122, on Ubuntu 21.04 5.11.0-1012-raspi, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.4.0-5.0.pre.122 at /home/user/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5acf7e98f1 (17 hours ago), 2021-07-20 19:58:58 -0700
    • Engine revision 9b270621e4
    • Dart version 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-338.0.dev)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • CHROME_EXECUTABLE = /snap/bin/chromium
[✓] VS Code (version 1.58.2)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.24.0
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Chromium 91.0.4472.164 snap
• No issues found!
```

I'm two days into this already and I've learned a lot but I'm reaching the point now where I'm a little stuck so any help is greatly appreciated and hopefully what I've done so far can help someone in the future

To be clear my problem is that my device doesn't appear in `flutter devices` and I can't debug with it in VS Code

I also tried flutter config --enable-android but still no show. I can run sdkmanager avdmanager adb all from the terminal but flutter does not show that there's any android toolchain present. Please help